# How to look for a key with value in Typescript Enum?

Tags: typescript

I would like to search an Enum with value, and get the key of it. This is what i have now:

```
  private find(value: MyEnum): string {
    for (const key in MyEnum) {
      if (value === MyEnum[key]) {
        return key;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Can we not make it simpler? It seems to be an overengineering..

Actually all i want is value.name() in Java.

EDIT: MyEnum is sth like this:

```
export enum MyEnum {
  YES = 'x',
  NO = 'y'
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at `MyEnum` at runtime, it will essentially be an object like this:

```
{ YES: 'x', NO: 'y' }
```

There is no automatic reverse lookup for objects in JavaScript, so you need to write something like your `find()` function to do it. So I don't think there's anything simpler, no.

Had your enum been [numeric](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#numeric-enums), TypeScript would give you those [reverse mappings automatically](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings):

```
enum MyEnum {
    YES = 1,
    NO = 0
}
const oneKey = MyEnum[1]; // "YES" (typed as string)
const zeroKey = MyEnum[0]; // "NO" (typed as string)
```

But alas, you are using a string enum, so there's no magical answer here.

---

*If* you often need to do a reverse lookup and don't want to keep iterating over arrays to do it, you can build a reverse-mapping object in advance with a helper function like this:

```
type ReverseMapping<T extends Record<keyof T, keyof any>> = {
    [K in T[keyof T]]: { [P in keyof T]: K extends T[P] ? P : never }[keyof T]
}

function reverseMapping<T extends Record<keyof T, keyof any>>(t: T): ReverseMapping<T> {
    const ret = {} as ReverseMapping<T>;
    (Object.keys(t) as Array<keyof T>).forEach(k => ret[t[k]] = k as any);
    return ret;
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
// do this once
const reverseMyEnum = reverseMapping(MyEnum); // reverseMyEnum: { x: "YES", y: "NO" }

// reuse reverseMyEnum for reverse lookups:
const xKey = reverseMyEnum.x; // xKey: "YES"
const yKey = reverseMyEnum.y; // yKey: "NO"
const randKey = reverseMyEnum[Math.random() < 0.5 ? "x" : "y"]; // randKey: "YES" | "NO"
```

Of course, the `reverseMapping()` function is possibly more "over-engineered" than `find()`, so it's up to you whether it's worth it to you.  I would tend to keep using `find()` (although more strongly typed, not that you've asked for that) unless I was running into some kind of problem with it (e.g., performance from constantly iterating through a truly enormous enum... unlikely).

Anyway hope that helps.  Good luck!