# How to infer the type of the enum litrally?

Tags: typescript

I have this dummy enum:

```
enum RadCheck {
  blank = 0,
  userDefined = 1,
  macAddress = 2,
}
const H = RadCheck[RadCheck.blank]
```

Currently, H is being infered as `string`, I want to infer it as `"blank"`, without having to cast it.

Is that possible?

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBASghgEwMIAtgGMDWUDeAoKKAIwBs4RsBeKABgBoCowBnYAJwBFgAzASxGAIo1AIwNCEOOgCCCBG2DNmwqACYGAXzzoA9iGYAXKAAkV8ZGiwBtc6gyYAdKXKYAuniA)

Comment: If by "without having to cast it" you mean that you don't want a type assertion anywhere in your code (btw, the preferred term in TS is "type assertion", not "cast") then no, this is impossible because of the missing feature at [ms/TS#50933](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50933). If you are willing to write a helper function or helper type to compute reverse enums for you, you can do it [this way](https://tsplay.dev/wQLjAW).  Which question are you asking?  And does this fully address the question or am I missing something?

Comment: @jcalz, yes that solves it thank you. I think I will stop using enums from now and start using normal objects with `as const`

Answer (score 1):

[Reverse mappings in enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings) are currently not given values of [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types); they are just `string`.  There is an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#50933](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50933) to support literal-type reverse values, but for now it's not part of the language.

---

If you want to proceed you'll need to work around it somehow, but it will involve a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) somewhere.  We can write a utility type to look up an enum's key by the value type:

```
type ReverseEnumLookup<T, V> =
  keyof { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends V ? K : never]: 0 }
```

That uses [key-remapping in a mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to filter the keys of `T` to just those whose values are assignable to `T`.  This is essentially the same operation as `KeysMatching` from [In TypeScript, how to get the keys of an object type whose values are of a given type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54520676/2887218).  It works like this:

```
type TestA = ReverseEnumLookup<typeof RadCheck, RadCheck.blank>;
// type TestA = "blank"
type TestB = ReverseEnumLookup<typeof RadCheck, RadCheck.macAddress>;
// type TestB = "macAddress"
type TestC = ReverseEnumLookup<typeof RadCheck, 12345>;
// type TestC = never
```

So you could proceed like

```
const H = RadCheck[RadCheck.blank] as ReverseEnumLookup<typeof RadCheck, RadCheck.blank>;
// const H: "blank"
console.log(H) // "blank"
```

but this is probably more annoying than useful.  Instead you could write a utility function that uses this type, which can reverse an arbitrary enum (such as in [How to look for a key with value in Typescript Enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52517682/2887218)):

```
function reverseEnumLookup<T extends object, const V extends T[keyof T]>(
  t: T,
  v: V
) {
  const ret = Object.entries(t).find(e => v === e[1]);
  if (ret === undefined) throw new Error("not found");
  return ret[0] as ReverseEnumLookup<T, V>;
}
```

which is probably more convenient to use:

```
const H = reverseEnumLookup(RadCheck, RadCheck.blank);
// const H: "blank"
console.log(H); // "blank"
```

You might even implement `reverseEnumLookup()` to just do an indexing, but the actual implementation is probably not as important as noting that the general operation you seek is a missing feature and needs a workaround with at least one type assertion or similar type-loosening somewhere.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBASghgEwMIAtgGMDWUDeAoKKAIwBs4RsBeKABgBoCowBnYAJwBFgAzASxGAIo1AIwNCEOOgCCCBG2DNmwqACYGAXzx4ALgE8ADsFjAAbu1YBRcBAAyAe3uYwBgDwAVOlABqAPmGMmMB69ty4UADaANJQ-FBBIWHuUHDK7tEAulDAAB46oAjK3lAA-FAxAFxQAuZsGVU0UFq6hsbuijrSKjBmFsDWkA5OLq76RqGwiKgYmF7wyGhYAHSk5Ji+ANx4APTbUGNtHV3UAESrFCctRlDtzDoAQt29bFY2Q85uBxPz01hzU4tMEtJDI5AolJsdnsDjcOo9TiDZPJFMxLjDbjokE9aq9Bo4PqNWt8ATMvCJVABmAAsAFZIbt9q1YXcsdQauxtOh7CA7lAABKNag-QERYUzFZkChZVImHH9N74kZfMJiv6TBbi87rLYMrk8nT8mhVM6SzCXPXMewkYBLEj2ADmAAoBQBKKAMk1rS54bhgEDoHS8blQBRygZ2RVuZK5fIgQpQexEABWGB0XgtBuKMYKaQiCQm7gyvkdjB0VU8jFMVW8eDd+EIGZDwAN1AA8snU0tQDo2LxFI6dC6lnw447jJR-KZhJRqMAIiIMi6toReGFHQoWzOmHGePxBG6dCg2PYAO7VYBnyxsY9sR0nED2A3cex+hAnJeMDdgNggJs6CI0NKyg9GGCrDFGXh+FszSNnyKihn04bvC4jqqrM6q-ECWofrq3K8nyxpauaeFWjadpOnyS7unsnoXNoQA)